# Get Value from Person or Group Type Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfield, sputility

How can I get Value from Person or Group Type Field from a List form. Context here is a SharePoint list. the point is I need to do this for validation purpose. So I need the value entered in this field by the user. I have tried using `SPutility` but it's not working.

Any other way possible?

Comment: Is the REST-API an option?

Comment: Yes why not. But the point is I need to do this for validation purpose. So I need the value entered in this field by the user (Not the values from the list items).

Comment: I think JQuery's the easiest approach for validation. What is your rule?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around for this. Though this can't be done with sputility. This is how we can pick value from **Person or group**/ **People picker field** :

http://howtolearnsharepoint.blogspot.in/2015/12/get-and-set-sharepoint-2013-people.html

This might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getItems(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {            
    //gets your data in console
    console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}

var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=ID,SpPerson/Title,SpPerson/Id&$expand=SpPerson";
getItems(urlForAllItems);
```

Comment: This doesn't solves my problem. Not the expected answer sorry. I need the value entered by the user currently for this purpose. That too from people picker filed.

Comment: can you elaborate what validation you want.

Comment: Please read my question and the answer which I have given again. In brief I just wanted to pick the value entered by user in the Newform.aspx for a list.(Field's data type is Person/Group).